# Input button using css after element

Tags: css

I've created a sliding button with css using the :after element.

The problem I'm having is that my "input" buttons don't seem to use the :after element and they don't slide like my normal buttons.

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_login; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Is there any way that I can use the :after element on this or is there any possible workaround?

edit: To add a little more info here is the css for the button.

```
.btn-cart {
  color: #3498db;
}
.btn-cart:hover,
.btn-cart:focus,
.btn-cart:active {
  background: none;
  border-color: transparent;
}
.btn-cart:hover:after,
.btn-cart:focus:after,
.btn-cart:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}
.btn-cart:after {
  background: #3498db;
}
input.btn-cart:hover,
button.btn-cart:hover,
input.btn-cart:focus,
button.btn-cart:focus,
input.btn-cart:active,
button.btn-cart:active {
  background: #3498db;
}
```

I have tried the ::after but that doesn't work :(

The button does not slide on any browser because the :after element isn't working on any input buttons.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Please provide more information such as the css code you are attempting to use. Would be helpful to see the class referenced at a minimum. Also which browsers have you tested in, what were results of each. Have you tried the CSS3 syntax of 2 colons? (::after)

Comment: Hey, sorry about this (I'm a noob here) I wrote "<input>" in my question and it got hidden which is why it made no sense, I didn't realise it was hidden. The problem is only with the input type buttons, the sliding function works on all but the input.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. This works for my input buttons, I changed "input" to "button" in my original code and added the word "login". See working code below,

```
<p><button type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_login; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button></p>
```